# How to start neo4j with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: neo4j

I am working with Neo4j and want to integrate it with Visual Studio 2015. At present, I have installed Neoj desktop version in my system. I have an issue regarding Neo4j.

Each time I open my application, I have to open Neo4j Desktop and start it.

Is there any way available to make neo4j start automatically when I open my application? If yes, what is it? Any references?

Comment: When you say "Each time I open my application", you refer to Visual Studio ?

Comment: A Neo4j Desktop project's "Graph" should stay running after you start it, as long as you do not reboot the computer, delete the project, stop the "Graph", or quit the Desktop window.

Comment: No ,I refer to my application.Suppose I started the graph ,I am able to enter the data to neo4j .But, if I stop the graph  and I enter my data to neo4j from visual studio ,it's showing authentication error.